# Pulling from database with sf::st_read() in parallel

Tags: r, postgresql, parallel-processing, r-sf

Is it possible to parallelize the `sf::st_read()` function?

```
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname="gisdb", user = "postgres",
    password="postgres", host = "127.0.0.1", port = 5432)

df <- sf::st_read(dsn = con, geom_column = "geom", query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE;")
```

Comment: Its probably not going to speed things up by much even if you can - you'll be limited by the database response, or the network speed, or R having to reassemble the parts.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'd still be interested in benchmarking this to see if I can save a few minutes.